# System crashes frequently

Tags: crash

I installed Lubuntu 13.10 as a dual boot with Windows XP on an e-machines.  Lubuntu crashes frequently, especially when I use the browser.  I can't close Lubuntu using Alt+SysRq+REISUB, must power off the computer. 
How can I log off without powering down?
How can I resolve the crashing problem?

Comment: Can you drop to a console (Alt-Shift-F1)? If so could you check the logs for some more info? (cat /var/log/messages)

Answer (score 0):

If it crashes frequently when you use the browser (I guess with some flash content), then it is likely a problem with your graphic cards driver. Either the driver has some bugs, or simply it can't control the graphic cards power saving features, so the card overheats. Try testing against this case with some graphic intensive programs. If it is confirmed then try using another VGA driver (fglrx vs radeon, nouveau vs nvidia), or simply don't use graphic intensive programs if you can.